# How to get all processes to a string?

Tags: python, psutil

There is the following code, how to display all processes in it with one line and remove from each .exe?

```
import psutil
for proc in psutil.process_iter():
    name = proc.name()
    print(name)
```

to get it

```
chrome, opera, svhost, ...
```

Comment: whats the problem in that code?

Comment: I need to get the output of processes in one line, and not separately

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get them in one line, use `sep` parameter in `print` function:

```
import psutil
enlisted = [proc.name() for proc in psutil.process_iter()]
print(*enlisted, sep = ' ')
```

Or there is `end` parameter too.

Answer (score 1):

```
import psutil
procs = [proc.name().replace('.exe', '') for proc in psutil.process_iter()]
print(', '.join(procs))
```

As mentioned by @Vicrobot, the print line could as well be replaced by

```
print(*procs, sep = ', ')
```

while keeping in mind that the default seperator of `print` is already `' '`.

.

Comment: Thanks, it works. How can I put any character before the output of the process and after?
as an example * chrome *, * svhost *, ..

Comment: You could concatenate within the list comprehension, which is not the most elegant way but it works:
`procs = ['* ' + proc.name() + ' *' for proc in psutil.process_iter()]`